# Several buttons in navbar on iOS

Tags: navigation, ios, human-interface-guideline, apple

I'm currently working on a app that basically follows Apple's HIG with title, back button and an additional button in navbar on all pages, but it's where my questions start.

It is a search/browse page with a back button on the left side and a toggle between list/map view on the right side of the navbar:

[image]

Now, I need a way to filter the searching/browsing through sliders.

Can I have this option next to the toggle in the navbar, in terms of UX, so the toggle behaviour doesn't change in the app?

[image]

And since Apple HIG says:

> Avoid crowding a navigation bar with additional controls, even if it looks like there’s enough space. **In general, a navigation bar should contain no more than the view’s current title, the back button, and one control that manages the view’s contents.** If you use a segmented control in the navigation bar, the bar shouldn’t display a title and it shouldn't contain any controls other than the segmented control.

Can they reject the app if we use this solution?

I have thought about the segmented control with toggle instead but we want the title in navbar as much as possible, and since we have a toolbar with four filter options already directly under the navbar, having the filters in terms of price there don't work.

Please help out because I'm running out of ideas on how to solve this!

Comment: We can't tell you if Apple can reject the app - that's only something Apple can tell you, and such a question isn't really a UX one. (Basically, Apple can decide whatever they like, and may not make the same decision from one day to the next). However, we can help you with how best to achieve the aim you have with your app though to best benefit the end user.

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear, i am obviously open for suggestions as how to solve this as good as possible! I was thinking of a dropdown-menu solution, but that would make the behaviour different from the other pages in the app, and probably only confuse the user... I am simply running out of ideas here... =(

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me that you should:

1. Change the toggle button to a button group (similar to [Segmented Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Controls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH15-SW1)) which clearly displays the two options. Toggle buttons are in most cases hard to understand.
2. Move the button group and place it underneath the row that says "Option, Option, Option, etc" since they become more close to the result.
3. Place the filtermenu that will open the sliders to the upper right corner where you initially placed the toggle button. That's where most apps place a "Edit" icon. For example that's where [Spotify](https://itunes.apple.com/se/app/spotify/id324684580) and [Mr Porter](https://itunes.apple.com/se/app/mr-porter/id481673241?mt=8) puts theirs.